# How to send NEW request inside Interceptor, without get circular dependecy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to send a New Request from my Http Interceptor. Always I am getting infinite loop.

I am using AngularJS

```
$injector.invoke(function($http) {
   $http({url: 'alert/find'}).then(function(resp) {
   defer.resolve(resp);
   console.log(resp);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I avoid loop infinite using

```
// First time returns true
if(response.config.url != 'myUrl/test') {
  // my new request to 'myUrl/test'
} else {
  return response
}

//Second time when intercept http, it will to return response
//normally, breaking the infinite loop behaviour
```

To get a new request:

```
$injector.get('$http').get('myUrl/test').success(function() {
// code goes here
});
```

These codes you can wrapper inside a interceptor [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: What is defer? Put up the code where defer is defined

Comment: Can you show the entire interceptor?

Comment: I have been update my answer with the solution! Thanks everybody